# Assigning all comments to one post in SQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

### What I want:

I want all comments which belong to a certain post to be shown underneath the corresponding post, using some some sort of loop to show all the *CommentText*s in a list.

E.g. if there are 3 comments with PostNr = 1, then these comments should be listed underneath the post which has the same PostNr.
*The comments are called *CommentText*
[Here's a link to the project so you see what it does for yourself.](http://studiosomniate.com/forum/show.php)

### Example:

p = post 
c = comment 

I have: 
pc 
pc 
pc 
I want: 
pccc 
Thanks in advance and if something is still unclear please tell me!

```html
<?php
$sql = "
SELECT posts.PostNr, Title, PostText, Date, CommentText
FROM posts, comments
WHERE posts.PostNr = comments.PostNr";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='post'><h1 class='title'>".$row["Title"]."</h1><br><p class='time'>".$row["Date"]."</p>
   <p class='message'> ".$row["PostText"]."</p>
   <i class='fa fa-reply' aria-hidden='true'></i>
   <i class='fa fa-heart' aria-hidden='true'></i>
    <div class='comments'>
     <div class='create-comment'>
      <form method='post' action='read_comments.php'>
       <div class='top-wrapper' style='width:100%'>
        <textarea rows='5' cols='50' name='CommentText' placeholder='Uw reactie'></textarea>
        <input class='Postnr' type='text' name='PostNr' value='".$row["PostNr"]."'>
       </div>
       <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Plaats'>
      </form>
     </div>

     <div class='all-comments'>
      <h2>Reacties</h2>
      <div class='comment'>
       <p class='message'>".$row["CommentText"]."</p>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: This is very unclear and there is no real question. Be more specific.

Comment: / What do you want

Answer (score 0):

A HTML-Paragraph `<p>` makes a line break after it.
Use:

```
<span class='message'>".$row["CommentText"]."</span>
```

Instead of:

```
<p class='message'>".$row["CommentText"]."</p>
```

I hope this, is what you want

Comment: It's not really what I meant, but thank you anyways!